# TagUI RPA Download File From Browser

Tags: file, rpa

I want to automatic download file from browser using tagUI.

How can i do this with tagUI?  I need Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't track Stack Overflow for user queries. For issues and questions, raise directly to the GitHub page - https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues

To download files, there are 2 ways.

First way is write the TagUI script to perform the steps as you would normally do to download the file, logging in, clicking whatever you do to download as if you are doing it manually.

Second way is if you are familiar with Python, you can use the download() function to perform the download (provided it is a publicly available URL) - https://github.com/tebelorg/RPA-Python#pro-functions